# Zebble template installation

Tags: xamarin-zebble, zebble

Zebble VSIX insn't working. I tried to install, but it stuck. With different pc and internet. Same result. Why? Zebble was been drop?

[image: Stuck]

Answer (score 0):

It stuck if you don't install UWP SDK Tool before. So, you just have to install UWP SDK Tools in the visual studio installer e try again after that. :)